# How to create hyperlink to macro code to cut and paste?

Tags: excel, vba

I have an Excel sheet with 5 tabs, column A in each is where I want a clickable cell.

When that cell is clicked, I want it to cut the 4 cells to the right of it on the same row and paste it on the next tab.
Clicking A1 would cut B1, C1, D1, E1 and paste it on the next tab, on the next empty row.
Same with the next tab until that row has made it to the final tab.

All the data is on the first sheet, all the others are empty.
Once I click on the first sheet I want it to move to the next one, then when I click it on the next one I want it to move to the third one.

So far I have code that creates hyperlinks on the cells I highlight, but it displays (sheet name! cell number). I want to display a specific txt instead, like (complete) or (received). The display varies for each tab.

The code I have in the first sheet moves the cut row to the second sheet.
I tried pasting that code in the next sheet to move it to the third sheet but I get an error.

Code in module

```vb
Sub HyperActive()
    Dim nm As String

    nm = ActiveSheet.Name & "!"
    For Each r In Selection
        t = r.Text
        addy = nm & r.Address(0, 0)
        ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=r, Address:="", SubAddress:= _
            addy, TextToDisplay:=r.Text
    Next r
End Sub
```

Code in sheet

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_FollowHyperlink(ByVal Target As Hyperlink)
    Dim r As Range

    Set r = Range(Target.SubAddress)

    r.Offset(0, 1).Resize(1, 4).Cut
    Sheets("Wash Bay").Select
    Worksheets("Wash Bay").Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
   
End Sub
```

Comment: What is the error message? Note - instead of using the `Worksheet_HyperLink` event, you might be better off using the [`Workbook_SheetFollowHyperlink`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.workbook.sheetfollowhyperlink) event. Then you'll only have one code instance (in the `ThisWorkbook` module), instead of code in multiple sheet modules.

Comment: it gives a reference isn't valid msg. then a run-time error '1004': Method 'range' of object'_worksheet failed. it highlights the set r= range(target.subaddress) part when I hit debug

Comment: honestly I am a complete rookie here I have no idea what you mean by using the workbook sheetfollowhyperlink lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest using the [`Workbook_SheetFollowHyperlink`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.workbook.sheetfollowhyperlink) event here. This is the *workbook*-level event, as opposed to the *worksheet*-level `Worksheet_FollowHyperlink` event.

From the docs:

> Occurs when you choose any hyperlink in Microsoft Excel...
>
> **Parameters**
>
> **`Sh`** :    The `Worksheet` object that contains the hyperlink
>
> **`Target`**: The `Hyperlink` object that represents the destination of the hyperlink

Add the following code to the `ThisWorkbook` module (not the sheet code module).

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetFollowHyperlink(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Hyperlink)
    If Sh.Index = Me.Worksheets.Count Then Exit Sub ' Do nothing if `Sh` is the last worksheet
      
    Dim nextWs As Worksheet
    Set nextWs = Me.Worksheets(Sh.Index + 1)
    
    With nextWs
        Dim lastRow As Long
        lastRow = .Range("B" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    End With
                
    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = Sh.Range(Target.SubAddress)

    rng.Offset(, 1).Resize(1, 4).Cut Destination:=nextWs.Range("B" & lastRow + 1)
    
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub
```

IMPORTANT NOTE: In its current state, this assumes that the workbook only has *worksheets* (no chart sheets, for example).

---

**EDIT**: You can use this revised code if the workbook contains other sheet types besides worksheets:

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetFollowHyperlink(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Hyperlink)
    Dim indx As Long
    indx = GetWorksheetIndex(Sh)
    
    If indx = Me.Worksheets.Count Then Exit Sub
    
    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = Sh.Range(Target.SubAddress)
      
    Dim nextWs As Worksheet
    Set nextWs = Me.Worksheets(indx + 1)
    
    With nextWs
        Dim lastRow As Long
        lastRow = .Range("B" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    End With
    
    rng.Offset(, 1).Resize(1, 4).Cut Destination:=nextWs.Range("B" & lastRow + 1)
    
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub

Private Function GetWorksheetIndex(ByVal ws As Worksheet) As Long
    Dim w As Worksheet

    For Each w In ws.Parent.Worksheets
        Dim counter As Long
        counter = counter + 1
        
        If w.Name = ws.Name Then
            GetWorksheetIndex = counter
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next w
End Function
```

**2nd EDIT**:

I think you can rewrite `HyperActive` to something like this:

```
Sub HyperActive(ByVal rng As Range)
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = rng.Parent
    
    Dim fullAddress As String
    fullAddress = "'" & ws.Name & "'!" & rng.Address
    
    ws.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=rng, Address:="", SubAddress:=fullAddress, TextToDisplay:=rng.Text
End Sub
```

Then in the main `Workbook_SheetFollowHyperlink` code, add the following line:

```
HyperActive rng:=nextWs.Range("A" & lastRow + 1)
```

Comment: cool thanks! , that's a much better way to do it instead of adding my original code to every sheet. so as far as the code in the module that creates the hyperlink cell; is there a way to get that to move along the tabs as well or do I need to have the link in place in row A for every tab? my first sheet contains about 3000 rows.

Comment: Do you mean loop through each worksheet and create the hyperlinks in column A?

Comment: ya so when cells B->E are cut and pasted to the next tab, a hyperlink gets created in cell A to be able to cut and paste into the next tab. if that is too much I am ok with pre-created links that are on column A in every tab. its just the module I have now only creates links on the first sheet, when I try to use it to create links on the second sheet that's when that error msg comes up when I try to use that link

Comment: Ah... so you need to rewrite `HyperActive` to work on a specific range, as opposed to `Selection`.

Comment: the workbook doesn't contain any chart sheets, its honestly just 4 columns in every sheet A B C D E. B->E is just filled with data for about 3000 rows. I want column A to be filled with hyperlinks to move the row from one sheet to the next. every tab is a department at work and the idea is when each department is done with a specific thing that is in the row, they click the link and it moves over to the next tab so that department can see it when they open their tab.

Comment: See my 2nd edit. Though I'm not sure the text of the newly created hyperlink will be right. When you click a hyperlink, do you want that hyperlink to remain on the current sheet, or move to the next one? Should the newly created hyperlink have the same text as the clicked hyperlink?

Comment: right on! its working , it creates a hyperlink when moving the data across the tabs but I was using the module to create the initial link in the first tab but now it gives me a msg ( argument not optional )

Comment: So keep that original `HyperActive` code and rename the new one to something else.

Comment: i feel guilty taking up so much of your time, ill try to work on the rest on my own. thank you so much for your help i really appreciate it . Cheers from the deep north of Canada!

Comment: Canada, eh? Making me want some poutine and Tim Hortons :-)

Comment: if i could send you some i would!